# Facebook iOS SDK 4.2 is giving compiler error

Tags: ios, facebook, sdk

I have downloaded the  Facebook iOS SDK 4.2 from https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk. When I try to compile the library, its giving an error "/facebook-ios-sdk-master/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKAppLinkResolver.m:23:9: 'Bolts/BFAppLink.h' file not found". Later, I have crosschecked in github and found that Bolts-IOS @ 51bde07 is empty. Can some one let us know is this the known issue or when facebook would be updating the source files?

Answer (score 1):

Bolts framework is linked as dependency. If you're cloning the source with git, you need to call `git submodule init`. Otherwise, I would suggest you to download from [Facebook Developer site](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios), as mentioned in the `README` file that's shown below [here](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk).

Excerpt below:

1. Download the SDK at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios or via
   Cocoapods by adding the 'FBSDKCoreKit', 'FBSDKLoginKit', and
   'FBSDKShareKit' pods.
2. Test your install: build and run the project
   at ~/Documents/FacebookSDK/Samples/Scrumptious/Scrumptious.xcodeproj
3. Check-out the tutorials available online at:
   https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started
4. Start coding! Visit https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios for tutorials
   and reference documentation.